# ForkJoinPool Constructor with parallelism

Tags: java

In ForkJoinPool, does parallelism constructor mean number of CPUs OR number of threads? If its number of CPUs, then how to set the max size of the ForkJoinPool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This constructor parameter stands for number of worker threads in the pool. By default it's equal to number of CPUs and this default is reasonable in most cases. You may want to change it if, for example, running several FJPs at the same time.

If you're going to alter thread count it's generaly a good idea to profile the application. Real performance results are almost always different from what you can expect.

Comment: Thank you. It seems the default Runtime.getAvailableProcessors() confused me little bit. So, for parallelism, apparently, its best to create a threadpool size of the same order as the available processors.